# Debugger command line arguments in Code::blocks

Tags: gcc, gdb, codeblocks

When debugging a program in Code::blocks, how do you specify command line arguments to be sent to the program being debugged. I can't find where to set this for the life of me and google searches bring up settings for debugging the compiler itself, rather than programs written in the compiler. It would be a strange thing to leave out.

Thanks,

Tim.

Answer (score 12):

Ah, looking with a visual studio head on. It's not in the project settings dialog but off the project menu:

Project->Set Programs Arguments

Comment: What a strange location for it.

Comment: Wanted to add that you need a Project in the workspace in order to "Set Programs Arguments" window to show and "Debug" tools too (at least in v.13.12)