# int main argc number of arguments

Tags: c++

Trying to have fun with Monte-Carlo simulation, I'm struggling with C++. I'm a mathematician and it's my first time with C++.

```
/* The main routine
 */

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timezone tz;
    double res,err;
    int loops,n,i;

    /* require correct number of arguments
     */
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,usage);
        exit(0);
    }

    n     = atoi(argv[1]);    /* first int */
    loops = atoi(argv[2]);    /* 2nd int */

    /* seed the random number using system time
     * tv.tv_sec contains time in seconds, tv.tv_usec in microseconds
     */
if((r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937)) == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: Could not create random number generator\n");
    exit(1);
  }
    gettimeofday( &tv, &tz );
    gsl_rng_set(r, tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec );


    for (i=0; i<100000; i++) gsl_rng_get (r);

    for (i=0; i<loops; i++)
    {
        res = mcint(n,&err);
        printf("%d  %g  %g\n",i,res,err);
    }

    return(1);
}
```

where mcint is my Monte-Carlo function.

The problem is argc doesn't have the correct number of arguments (3).
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: This isn't clear.  How are you invoking this program, and what is the value of `argc`?

Comment: This is nothing wrong with the program itself, it matters how you are running the program. Specifically what parameters you give it.

Comment: I'm running the programm as it is. How should I give it a paramater ?

Comment: Are you using visual studio to run it? If so by default it runs with no params and you need to modify the execution options to add you values

Comment: My ide is Code::Blocks with a mingw32-g++ compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argc is the number of arguments when you call your programme from the command line.

Your programme expects 3 arguments.  The first is always the name of the programme executable. So it needs to additional arguments that you must provide: the first is the first intereger (n) and the second is the number of iteration you want it to perform.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to compile the programme and call it from the command line:

```
  MYMONTECARLO 100 1000
```

If you're under an IDE look in your manual how to provide such runtime arguments.  For code::blocks for example, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6716848/3723423)